# How can I extract .example class content from data variable and set to .test class?

Tags: jquery

I can't find any example on the internet.
I want to get paragraph from other webpage on my domain and set to `.test` class. 
So far I'm using `.get()` method to get HTML content and I'm passing everything to data variable.
How can I extract `.example` class content from data variable and set to `.test` class?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("data.html", function(data) {
        $(".test").text(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("data.html", function(data) {
        $(".test").text($(data).find(".example").text()); // or find(".example").html() depending on what you want
    });
});
```

Comment: html file<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 
       <div class="section">
                <p>
       Very good  I urge, then, first of all, 
                   </p>
                          
              </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: JQuery fiel --> <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; ">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get("data.html", function(data) {
    $(".test").text($(data).find(".example").text());
    });
});
 
</script>

</head>
<body>
              <div class="test">
              <p> bla bla bal blabalb</p>
              </div>
            
</body>
</html>